# Did Github remove support for domain names like 'username.github.io'?

Tags: github, github-pages

I recently wanted to switch away from Jekyll to Hugo but I run into some troubles

I have two repositories, which are basically the same but with different names

https://github.com/MaikKlein/maikklein.github.io

https://github.com/MaikKlein/blog

The first one should be reachable from https://maikklein.github.io/ and the second one is reachable from https://maikklein.github.io/blog

But https://maikklein.github.io/ is not reachable, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

For user sites like https://maikklein.github.io/, use the master branch for your code.

You currently have your site in the gh-pages branch.

Comment: This commit you made fixed the issue:
https://github.com/MaikKlein/maikklein.github.io/commit/adcb0099106e772332a8fa5224737b14dc2829e0